# Cant refresh firebase IdToken

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I read lots of questions on SO but i cant resolve my problem. My problem is that I cant get refreshed token from firebase.

I have android client and before sending request to my ASP Core Api I am checking token with this code:

```
public static void checkToken(Context context)
{
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    ErrorHandler errorHandler = new ErrorHandler(context);
    if (auth!=null)
    {
        FirebaseUser mUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
        if (mUser!=null){
            mUser.getIdToken(true)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                String idToken = Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getToken();
                                UserSP.init(context);
                                UserSP.write(idToken);
                            } else {
                                ApiLogItem eerr = new ApiLogItem(0,"","","Dogodila se greška prilikom provjere tokena:\n"+task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(),"");
                                errorHandler.LogEvents(eerr);
                                // Handle error -> task.getException();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }else{
            //user nije logiran
        }

    }
    else {
        // inicijalizacija firebase-a nije dobro prošla
    }

}
```

And on my ASP core API I am verifying token with this code:

```
try
    {
        var auth = FirebaseApp.GetInstance("auth");
        var authInstance = FirebaseAdmin.Auth.FirebaseAuth.GetAuth(auth);
        FirebaseToken decodedToken = await authInstance.VerifyIdTokenAsync(idToken);

}
catch (FirebaseAdmin.Auth.FirebaseAuthException faex)
{
    _logger.Error("Token nije ispavan - istekao je. Message: " + faex.Message + "; Firebase time: ");
    context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Neautorizirana akcija.");
    return;
}
```

But most of time result is:

> Firebase ID token expired at x. Expected to be greater than y.

What am I missing?

Comment: You might want to pass the token you get through https://jwt.io/ to see what value its `exp` has.

Comment: Yes i pass token to jw.io and token has expired. Question is why I cant get refreshed token with above code?

Comment: I don't know what the `UserSP` calls do, but would recommend instead simply logging the ID token in the Android code, and also checking that in jwt.io. It seems quite unlikely that it consistently returns an expired token there.